# How to know bytes read(offset) of BufferedReader?

Tags: java, io

I want to read file line by line.
BufferedReader is much faster than RandomAccessFile or BufferedInputStream.
But the problem is that I don't know how many bytes I read.
How to know bytes read(offset)?
I tried.

```
String buffer;
int offset = 0;

while ((buffer = br.readLine()) != null)
    offset += buffer.getBytes().length + 1; // 1 is for line separator
```

I works if file is small.
But, when the file becomes large, offset becomes smaller than actual value.
How can I get offset?

Comment: What bigger task are you trying to achieve? It's fundamentally tricky due to the internal buffer (and encodings, and different line endings).

Comment: I want to get offsets of start of lines. So, I use that offsets to read some part of file using RandomAccessFile later.

Comment: You are assuming that there is only one line separator byte, e.g. \n. Can you assume that?

Comment: Actually, I used line.separator instead of 1.

Answer (score 9):

There is no simple way to do this with `BufferedReader` because of two effects: Character endcoding and line endings. On Windows, the line ending is `\r\n` which is two bytes. On Unix, the line separator is a single byte. `BufferedReader` will handle both cases without you noticing, so after `readLine()`, you won't know how many bytes were skipped.

Also `buffer.getBytes()` only returns the correct result when your default encoding and the encoding of the data in the file accidentally happens to be the same. When using `byte[]` <-> `String` conversion of any kind, you should **always** specify exactly which encoding should be used.

You also can't use a counting `InputStream` because the buffered readers read data in large chunks. So after reading the first line with, say, 5 bytes, the counter in the inner `InputStream` would return 4096 because the reader always reads that many bytes into its internal buffer.

You can have a look at NIO for this. You can use a low level `ByteBuffer` to keep track of the offset and wrap that in a `CharBuffer` to convert the input into lines.

Comment: There is no simple way to do this with BufferedReader because it does both buffering and new line detection. BTW, thanks for hint about ByteBuffer and CharBuffer

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that should work. It assumes UTF-8, but you can easily change that.

```
import java.io.*;

class main {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        ByteCountingLineReader r = new ByteCountingLineReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(toUtf8("Hello\r\nWorld\n")));

        String line = null;
        do {
            long count = r.byteCount();
            line = r.readLine();
            System.out.println("Line at byte " + count + ": " + line);
        } while (line != null);

        r.close();
    }

    static class ByteCountingLineReader implements Closeable {
        InputStream in;
        long _byteCount;
        int bufferedByte = -1;
        boolean ended;

        // in should be a buffered stream!
        ByteCountingLineReader(InputStream in) {
            this.in = in;
        }

        ByteCountingLineReader(File f) throws IOException {
            in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(f), 65536);
        }

        String readLine() throws IOException {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            if (ended) return null;
            while (true) {
                int c = read();
                if (ended && baos.size() == 0) return null;
                if (ended || c == '\n') break;
                if (c == '\r') {
                    c = read();
                    if (c != '\n' && !ended)
                        bufferedByte = c;
                    break;
                }
                baos.write(c);
            }
            return fromUtf8(baos.toByteArray());
        }

        int read() throws IOException {
            if (bufferedByte >= 0) {
                int b = bufferedByte;
                bufferedByte = -1;
                return b;
            }
            int c = in.read();
            if (c < 0) ended = true; else ++_byteCount;
            return c;
        }

        long byteCount() {
            return bufferedByte >= 0 ? _byteCount - 1 : _byteCount;
        }

        public void close() throws IOException {
            if (in != null) try {
                in.close();
            } finally {
                in = null;
            }
        }

        boolean ended() {
            return ended;
        }
    }

    static byte[] toUtf8(String s) {
        try {
            return s.getBytes("UTF-8");
        } catch (Exception __e) {
            throw rethrow(__e);
        }
    }

    static String fromUtf8(byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            return new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
        } catch (Exception __e) {
            throw rethrow(__e);
        }
    }

    static RuntimeException rethrow(Throwable t) {

        throw t instanceof RuntimeException ? (RuntimeException) t : new RuntimeException(t);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use `RandomAccessFile`

```
     RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(filePath, "r");
     while ((cur_line = raf.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(curr_line);
        // get offset
        long rowIndex = raf.getFilePointer();
     }
```

to seek by offset do:

`raf.seek(offset);`

Answer (score -2):

I am wondering your final solution, however, I think using long type instead of int can meet the most situation in your code above.

Comment: This would solve nothing?

Answer (score -3):

If you want to read a file line by line, I would recommend this code:

```
import java.io.*;
class FileRead 
{
 public static void main(String args[])
  {
  try{
  // Open the file that is the first 
  // command line parameter
  FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("textfile.txt");
  // Use DataInputStream to read binary NOT text.
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
  String strLine;
  //Read File Line By Line
  while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
  // Print the content on the console
  System.out.println (strLine);
  }
  //Close the input stream
  in.close();
    }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
  System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
  }
  }
}
```

I always used that method in the past, and works great!

Source: [Here](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/java-read-file-line-by-line.shtml)

Comment: You response it's a little wrong, because you should close external resources in a finally block, also you don't answer the question, and beside this he is using something similar, but with a more compact code example.

Comment: If it comes from rose india, you should assume it is only mostly right.  You are better off reading just about any other web site.